# Access elements in JSON after ajax request

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have spent the last couple of hours trying to figure out this. 
I make an ajax request using JQuery. I get a response in string format and I use

```
jQuery.parseJSON(response);
```

to convert it to Object.
This is my response:

```
{
    "columns": ["n"],
    "data": [
        [{
            "extensions": {},
            "labels": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/labels",
            "outgoing_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/relationships/out",
            "traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/traverse/{returnType}",
            "all_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
            "property": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/properties/{key}",
            "self": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168",
            "properties": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/properties",
            "outgoing_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}",
            "incoming_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/relationships/in",
            "create_relationship": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/relationships",
            "paged_traverse": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}",
            "all_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/relationships/all",
            "incoming_typed_relationships": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/168/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}",
            "metadata": {
                "id": 168,
                "labels": []
            },
            "data": {
                "name": "1"
            }
        }]
    ]
}
```

I try to access specific elemets of this object but I get nothing back. When I try this

```
var test = json.data;
```

it works but how can I access the values saved in metadata.
I try this but I get "undefined":

```
var test = json.data.metadata.id;
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: `Data` is an array containing arrays, so you will not be able to access it using object notation.

Comment: Try this json.data[0][0].metadata.id;

Comment: As folks are pointing out, it's an array.   Those brackets are what say array.   You'll notice your data part has two brackets right after it, meaning double array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an array, so you've to use index

```
var test = json.data[0][0].metadata.id;
```

`json.data[0]` returns `[{...}]` and again `[{...}][0]` returns `{...}` which has `metadata` Object, which in turn as `id` property which is what you need.

Comment: @dkar happens. Glad to have helped you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

json.data is a double array.

This should work:

```
var test = json.data[0][0].metadata.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var test = json.data[0][0].metadata.id;
```

`json.data` is an array of arrays.